# Disconnected cable in the ATX power connector but PC still runs normally, should I keep using it?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

So, I have a AeroCool KCAS-600W PSU, and today while I was using my computer I noticed that a orange cable had poped out of the socket. So I basicly grabed it and put it back into place. Please the in cossideration that the cable was disconected from the contactor, so now there is problably bearly any contact.

What I want to know is if I should keep using my computer, since I need it for school and to studie for college exams. Bear in mind that the PC is working flawless, but im afraid that it might damage other parts before I get the new PSU.

[image: Picture of the 24 pin connector with indication of the faulty cable]

Comment: [Here](https://www.lifewire.com/thmb/ImFRroX9zXocLj5hSS7PEJq8S3g=/1500x1000/filters:fill(auto,1)/atx-24-pin-12v-power-supply-pinout-2624578-ADD-FINAL-d0b3d259d8f842af9e2481f2b75a447b.png) is a layout of the 24-pin connector.  The orange cable is +3.3v.  It's pin 12, and it's detachable; you should be fine.  **However, I offer no warranty for this conclusion**  You should, of course, replace the PSU and or cable if your current PSU is modular.

Comment: Thanks for the response. At the moment I'm trying to get a RMA, because I only owned it for a few months, at the moment I'm just glad that I caught it before it turned into a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably fine, but I'd recommend getting this fixed more permanently.

This wire is one of four +3.3V wires in a 24-pin ATX connector. Given that the load on +3.3V lines has decreased significantly since this standard was introduced and that modern ATX power supplies have only one +3.3V rail, three wires should be plenty. Exception would be if motherboard makes additional assumptions and powers something exclusively from this wire, but in that case you'd notice it's not working properly.

To avoid sparking and charring due to poor connection you should disconnect the 24-pin connector, reseat the wire in question properly and reconnect the connector, making sure the orange wire doesn't pop out.

If your PSU is modular, you could consider replacing the ATX cable (thanks @Ramhound for this idea in the comments).

Comment: Sadly it is not modular, at the momment I'm trying to get a RMA because I'm still in the warranty period, but if for some reason I cant get it, I'll try fixing it my self like you said, I junt need to find a good explanation on how to remove the contactor from the inside of the socket. But again thanks for the anwser, I fell a little bit less scaried now.

Comment: The pin has small barbs on the sides. You need to flatten the 2 barbs to allow the pin to come out, then using a sharp blade, bend the pins back out to around 45°. Now push the pin back in and it should almost click into place. Give it a light pull to check it's secure in its housing. Search YouTube for "Remove ATX Pins", there are plenty of videos.